# How to pass value of a form to another form PHP?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have a form A in index.php which I need to pass the value of 'notebook_id' to formB in create_new_note.php. I used POST method to do this but it is not working.

form A in index.php

```html
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="newNotebookModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="newNotebookModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <center><h5 class="modal-title" id="newNotebookModalLabel">Create a New Notebook</h5></center>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="forms-sample" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="notebook_name_label">Notebook Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="notebook_name" id="notebook_name" placeholder="Notebook Name">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-fw">Cancel</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Create"/>
            </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Form B

```html
<form class="forms-sample" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="note_title_label">Title</label>
      <input type="hidden" name="notebook_id" value="<?php echo $notebook_id; ?>">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="note_title" id="note_title" placeholder="Title">
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <textarea class="form-control" name ="note_content"id="note_content" rows="40"></textarea>
     </div>
     <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-fw">Cancel</button>
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Create"/>
</form>
```

I used MVC framework, hence this is my Controller code and Model code

```php
// Controller

function addNotebook($std_id) {
    $notebook = new ManageNotesModel();
    $notebook->std_id = $std_id;
    $notebook->notebook_name = $_POST['notebook_name'];
   
    if($notebook->addNotebook() > 0) {
      $message = "Your notebook has been created!";
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');
      window.location = '../ManageNotesView/create_new_note.php'</script>";
    }
  }
```

```php
// Model
function addNotebook(){
  $sql = "insert into notebook(std_id,  notebook_name)values(:std_id, :notebook_name)";
  $args = [':std_id'=> $this->std_id, ':notebook_name'=>$this->notebook_name];
  $stmt = DB::run($sql, $args);
  $count = $stmt->rowCount();

  return $count;
}
```

Please help me, I'm new to this I tried to make way through it, but cant seem to figure out whats wrong

Comment: if you are navigating from a web page to another you can save your data in a query string or in session and retrieve it in the other page

Answer (score 0):

As I see your code is creating a new row in the database. After saving row into database you want to know the last inserted `id` of the entity called Notebooks. Reuse that value and pass it into your template of creating titles. If your MVC framework does not know the last inserted id, you should customize it and add functionality to do that.
Check [last_inserted_id](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp)